# How does the 'Basic Training' trait and the 'Special Forces' trait work?

Tags: state-of-decay, state-of-decay-lifeline

Most soldiers have the 'Basic Training' trait:
[image]

...while there are some with the 'Special Forces' trait:
[image]

How do these traits affect the soldiers who have them? Do those two traits have any differences?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

These traits are among those added in the DLC Lifeline. If you unpack the **Beltway.pak** file and examine the characters.xml file inside, you will be able to find all characters, traits and trait effects in this DLC.

Basic Training:

- +7 Encumbrance limit
- Cardio + 2
- Shooting + 2

Special Forces:

- Cardio + 4
- Wits +2
- Shooting +4
- Bonus Wits XP gain

Sniper Qualified

- Wits + 2
- Shooting + 4

You might notice that Alicia Hawkes has Shooting level 7 right at the beginning, since she has both Basic Training and Sniper Qualified traits.